# Reloading Salt grains

Tags: automation, saltstack

I'd like to download a grains file from external source during the `state.highstate` is run. The file is not supposed to change usually - I'm only using this mainly for the initial provisioning.

So it seems like I just want a `file.managed` state that will put the right contents into `_grains` (I'm using a standalone client) and then call `saltutil.sync_grains`. But how do I call a function? It's going to be a state with `watch` configured, but I don't see a state that would help me do that.

Comment: Arrrgh, ignore my close vote, I misread the entire question. Sorry.

Comment: @pauska no worries :)

Comment: I don't suppose you could mention the software you're using here...

Comment: It's [SaltStack](http://saltstack.com/community.html)

Comment: @ChrisS It's in the title and in the tag -> "salt". I capitalised it in the title now.

Comment: noramly i will restart salt when this happens and i sometimes will have my salt process in supervisor so that it will come back on its own. and then i also have salt start from cron. since only one version of salt will run it works well fix supervisor and kill the cron one remotly and supervisor should start salt under its own control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saltutil.sync_grains - it is module call, not state.
You need run this module with state "module" https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html#module-salt.states.module
But you can just start minion only after deployng right configuration (see salt-cloud).
For dynamic parametrizing best practice is pillar:
https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html

Comment: and you can take full control of grains with this modult
http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#module-salt.modules.grains